# Connection monitoring tool

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring, network-monitor, internet

I'm having some problems with connection (randomly drops) and need to check whether it is problem with specific parts of hardware. Which is why I am looking for a tool for monitoring connection over longer periods that logs especially the drops.

I can't predict when the drops will happen and don't have time to be waiting for and check it manually, so I need something to automate it for me as I leave the device connected directly to different parts of hw.

Can you recommend a fitting tool for that? (for Windows 10)

Comment: I assume there is not only hardware connections issues, also you have network connection problems also. Isn't it?

Comment: Aye. I am trying to figure out whether it is problem with hardware or network. But connecting directly to the network and checking it in person for long period of time would be bit problematic, which is why i look for a monitoring tool.

Comment: You didn't provide any price information but you might have a look at this page: https://www.pcwdld.com/cisco-network-monitoring-tools